# Angular rxjs: method does not wait for promise to finish

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a method:

```js
public async findByEmail(email: string): Promise<User> {
    await this.findAll().toPromise().then(users => {
        users.forEach(user => {
            if (user.email === email) {
                console.log(user);
                return of(user);
            }
        });
    });
    return null;
}
```

which calls this method:

```js
  public findAll(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.userUrl) as Observable<User[]>;
  }
```

When I call the `findByEmail` method, I get `null`. I think this is because of the nested loop inside.

How do I return instances of a user (or the promise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `.forEach` method doesn't return anything. Try using `.filter` instead:

```js
public async findByEmail(email: string): Promise<User> {
  const users = await this.findAll().toPromise();
  const withSameEmail = users.filter(user => user.email === email);
  return withSameEmail;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In method findByEmail() does not return promise.

Return with directly in front of 'await' like below.

```
return await this.findAll().toPromise()
```